# Android Permission: Opposite to "Full Internet Access"

Tags: android, permissions

In Android an application can request the `android.permission.INTERNET` permission. This gets translated by Android for the UI to "**full** Internet access".

Is there something like "restricted Internet Access"? What does the word "**full**" mean here? Are there any other permissions which enable Internet Access but only to specific sites?

*I wrote an application which only needs access to one url and only needs a HTTP Connection to download this url. Do I need the `INTERNET`-Permission or is there something less which still suffices my needs?*

Comment: I've mentioned that Android's permission architecture is a big mess. I receive many comments from users, who don't like the permissions I add to my apps. INTERNET is one of those: when a user is asked to give your app the "full internet access", it looks like he must give your app the freedom to do absolutely anything with his internet connection. Many users don't like it. So it's still a big problem, that surely needs to be resolved by the Android guys.

Comment: @Egor: If would have accepted your comment if it was an answer. So thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`INTERNET` Allows applications to open network sockets.

USED FOR INTERNET ACCESS... There is no other permission and the word FULL is meaningless

However note these permissions:

`ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` Allows applications to access information about networks

`ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` Allows applications to access information about Wi-Fi networks

`CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE` Allows applications to change network connectivity state

Comment: The word FULL is meaningful. You can access the Internet without the INTERNET permission. The permission only protects the java libraries from accessing the Internet. But there are other ways. See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59301

Answer (score 0):

See the following Android Security Discussion for details about the technical limitations : http://groups.google.com/group/android-security-discuss/browse_thread/thread/ec7a9b85e77c6d98